# TeeChart for Android DateTime FormatException

Tags: xamarin.android, teechart

I've been evaluating TeeChart for Mono/Android but every time I try to run the sample projects my emulators keep throwing exceptions:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
 at System.DateTime.Parse  (string,System.IFormatProvider,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles) [0x00027] in /Users  /builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-4.2-series/804357b4/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:830

 at System.DateTime.Parse (string,System.IFormatProvider) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-4.2-series/804357b4/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:818

 at System.DateTime.Parse (string) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-4.2-series/804357b4/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:813

 at Steema.TeeChart.Chart.BetaNotExpired () <IL 0x0000c, 0x000cf>

 at Steema.TeeChart.Chart.InternalDraw (Android.Graphics.Canvas) <IL 0x00001, 0x0004b>

 at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.Draw (Android.Graphics.Canvas,System.Drawing.Rectangle) <IL 0x000c4, 0x004ef>

 at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.Draw (Android.Graphics.Canvas) <IL 0x00007, 0x00097>

 at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.OnDraw (Android.Graphics.Canvas) <IL 0x00055, 0x001a3>

 at Android.Views.View.n_OnDraw_Landroid_graphics_Canvas_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-4.2-series/804357b4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-12/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:9297

 at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.69af4743-db01-4501-8f13-77deb4a4e86e (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00012, 0x00033>
```

Based on the stack trace I'm guessing it has something to do with the BetaNotExpired and maybe a look-up value, but I just requested and received the evaluation version today.  Does anyone know how to get TeeChart working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. This beta release expires on July the 31st. I forgot to use a culture neutral mechanism. I used *DateTime.Parse("31/07/2012")* while you'd probably need *DateTime.Parse("07/31/2012")* or *DateTime.Parse("2012/07/31")*. So I changed TeeChart.Monodroid.dll to use a culture neutral mechanism converting DateTime values to universal time with [DateTime.ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx). You can download the new assembly [here](http://tinyurl.com/c8ey5zk). It was compiled with [Mono for Android 4.2.3 beta](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_for_Android_4.2.3). If necessary I could also compile it for 4.2. Please let me know if the bug fix doesn't solve the problem at your end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried the new assembly but still ran into the same problem even using the example 'MonoAndroidDemo'.

Comment: I was able to get it working my changing my emulator into en_GB to match the parsing expectations you had... this should be enough for me to proceed with testing, but if you want me to test any other changes on my en_US please let me know and I will spin off a test.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated the assembly to use ticks instead of parsing a DateTime string. It worked fine for me here with a en_US emulator. Can you please download and test it again?

Comment: Works like a charm with en_US.  Thanks.

Comment: @NathanPalmer I'm glad to hear that. As an update, a new beta has been posted: http://www.steema.com/entry/116/TeeChart_.NET_Mono_for_Android_Library_BETA_update. We expect the next version being the release one.